# Octave - dataframe column names?

Tags: dataframe, octave

I'm importing a csv into octave with the dataframe package. I've not been able to find any information about how to extract the header names, can anyone help, or suggest an alternative?

Comment: Please add some sample data (the header and the first 5 lines of your file) and what you've tried so far. I've used dataframe, csv2cell (from io package) and dlmread/csvread (in core) many times whithout problems.

Comment: Cheers for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

So i wasnt having trouble reading the data in nor seeing the names of the columns. What I was looking for was a way to get a list of the column names because i am using it for an application where the names will change depending on the csv. Turns out that df.colnames, where df is the dataframe name, is what i wanted. I found that colnames is an attribute of a dataframe, so i took a stab to see if df.colnames would work.